# I am trying to sort my nested hashmap using values in java but couldn't get it

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, treemap

Here is my example hashmap details and need to sort based on the number at end integer value.

```
Input:

{First={
       How={H=9},
       Are={A=1}, 
       You={U=325}},    
Second={
       Are={A=19}, 
       You={U=110}, 
       HOW={H=3}}
}


Expected output should be:

{First={
       You={U=325}       
       How={H=9},
       Are={A=1}}, 
Second={
       You={U=110}
       Are={A=19}, 
       HOW={H=3}}
}
```

Any option is there to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.HashMap` is a fundamentally unordered concept. `LinkedHashMap` (a subclass) sorts in insertion order: If you add first `[k1,v1]`, then `[k3,v3]` then `[k2,v2]`, that's also the exact order they are reported if you iterate through either its `.keySet()`, or its `.values()`, or its `.entrySet()`.

There's also `java.util.TreeMap` which sorts the inputs: If you add `[k1,v1]`, then `[k3,v3]` then `[k2,v2]`, it will return `[k1,k2,k3]` if you e.g. ask its `.keySet()`, assuming that you either provided a comparator when you constructed the treemap that sorts k1/k2/k3 in that order, or that the key's type has a natural order and that is how it sorts.

**It is not possible to sort according to value**. You can't involve the value associated with your key when trying to come up with a comparator for your TreeMap.

Thus, what you want (have a j.u.map that is ordered according to some property of the values, using the basic tools available in the java.util package) is impossible, unless you hand-write an entire map implementation yourself.